# How to show error on duplicate email in reactJs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a MERN project. I have a form data. i want to insert in my database. Data is successfully inserted but **I want to check duplicate email from my database and show error on reactjs page(like react toastify)**

**basically i want to show some error to user**

*so how to fetch email from backend and show some result in reactjs.*

**As there are some same questions but it would't help me**

*So please give me some suggestions how can i do it?*

**register.js**

```
const Register = () => {
  const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState({
    identity: "",
    names: "",
    phone: "",
    email: "",
    city: "",
    address: "",
    subject: "",
    classes: "",
    message: "",
  });

  

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "/register",
      data: JSON.stringify(newUser),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    }).then((response) => {
        toast.dark(`${newUser.names}  registered Sucessfully `, {
          position: "top-center",
          autoClose: 5000,
          hideProgressBar: false,
          closeOnClick: true,
          pauseOnHover: true,
          draggable: true,
          progress: undefined,
          });
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        
        if (error.response) {
          console.log(error.response.data);
        }
      });
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setNewUser({ ...newUser, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
```

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
const { identity, names, phone, email, city, address, subject, classes, message } = req.body

```
// if (!identity || !names || !phone || !email || !city || !address || !subject || !classes || !message) {
//     return res.status(422).json({ error: "Please mark all the field" })
// }

try {

    const userExit = await User.findOne({ email: email })
    if (userExit) {
        // res.status(422).json({ error: "Email already exit" })
        alert("email already exit")
        
    }
    // else if (password != cpassword) {
    //     return res.status(422).json({ error: "password and confirm password don not match" })
    // }
   
        const user = new User({identity ,names,  phone,email,city,address, subject, classes, message })
        await user.save()
        res.status(201).json({ message: "user registered successfulluy" })
      
    
    
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```

})

**auth.js**

```
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    const { identity, names, phone, email, city, address, subject, classes, message } = req.body
    

    try {

        const userExit = await User.findOne({ email: email })
        if (userExit) {
            // res.status(422).json({ error: "Email already exit" })
            alert("email already exit")
            
            const user = new User({identity ,names,  phone,email,city,address, subject, classes, message })
            await user.save()
            res.status(201).json({ message: "user registered successfulluy" })
          
        
        
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the error handler. You are already checking if the user exists. But instead of sending a `201` code, send an error code (`400` suggested), which will trigger the error catcher (`.catch()`) in  your frontend. There you can check if the status is `400` through `error.response.status` and toggle a popup component to display an error message.

Backend:

```
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
const { identity, names, phone, email, city, address, subject, classes, message } = req.body


try {
    const userExists = await User.findOne({ email: email })
    if (userExists) return res.status(400).json({ error: "Email already exit" });
        
    const user = new User({identity ,names,  phone,email,city,address, subject, classes, message });
    await user.save();
    res.status(201).json({ message: "user registered successfully" });        
} catch (err) {
    // Your server error handling...
    console.log(err)
}
```

Frontend:

```
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "/register",
      data: JSON.stringify(newUser),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    }).then((response) => {
        toast.dark(`${newUser.names}  registered Sucessfully `, {
          position: "top-center",
          autoClose: 5000,
          hideProgressBar: false,
          closeOnClick: true,
          pauseOnHover: true,
          draggable: true,
          progress: undefined,
          });
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response.status === 400) {
          // This line is for toggling the popup component
          shouldShowErrorMessage(true);
          console.log(error.response.data);
        }
      });
  };
```

Comment: can you please show how to do it...i have tried but god knows what is coming!!!

Comment: @anitaSingh added

Comment: showing ```'shouldShowErrorMessage' is not defined```.

Comment: it is a handler function to toggle between error and non error status, you should define it @anitaSingh

Comment: as @nima said, its a handler that you should define yourself to hide/show a component. Usually we use `useState` for it. @anitaSingh